# Makerule only runs one rule

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write my first Makefile. I currently have just 3 rules. When I run "make", only the first rule is executed and then make exits without running the other 2. There is nothing complicated with my Makefile. I even tried reducing the number of rules down to 2 but I get the same results. Here's what I have so far.

```
SRC = src/analytics.js

lint:
    jshint $(SRC)

build: $(SRC)
    cat $^ > build/analytics.js

min: build
    uglifyjs --no-mangle build/analytics.js > build/analytics.min.js
```

When I run make on here's what I get I just get the message that the lint rule was executed: `jshint src/analytics.js`

I'm running make 3.81 on Mac OS 10.8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run just 'make', make will do just the default target which is normally the first target - in your case 'lint:'.

If 'lint' has dependencies, then you need to list them. Eg:

```
lint: dep1 dep2
```

Make will do dep1 and dep2 before doing lint.

If you want all three things above to run with a single call to just 'make' add this target above your other targets:

```
all: lint build min
```

You can put them in the order you want them to occur. I called the target 'all' because that's what it does, not that it means anything special to make.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you have a target name that doesn't represent an actual file, you should be marking the target as phony, *i.e.*, `.PHONY: all`.